# Ищу подобный ui как у unigui

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, ui

Ищу подобный ui как у unigui формы, окна, кнопки итд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желательно бесплатный, может кто то сталкивался.

Answer (score 1):

Unigui использует компоненты ExtJS. Всвязи с этим можно выбрать одну из предлагаемых тем с unigui. Для изменения выбранной темы в рантайме можно выполнить Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet(...);
Так же тему можно кастомизировать следующими способами:

1. Изменить css текущей темы
2. Написать свой override css
3. Кастомизировать тему посредством sencha themer
4. Кастомизировать тему в scss установив ext trial, либо купив ext cmd заменяя css из каталога build